# How can I create an empty python package?

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I would like to create an empty (meta)package using the poetry tool, mainly to simplify bringing together a list of dependencies. If I create my project.toml as follows:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry"]

[tool.poetry]
name = "metapackage"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "My empty metapackage"
authors = ["Me"]
license = "MIT"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
numpy = "*"
```

Then execute `poetry build`, I get an error:

```
$ mkdir -p metapackage
$ python -m poetry build --no-interaction --format wheel -vvvUsing virtualenv: /Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37
Building metapackage (1.0.0)

[ValueError]
metapackage is not a package.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clikit/console_application.py", line 131, in run
    status_code = command.handle(parsed_args, io)
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clikit/api/command/command.py", line 120, in handle
    status_code = self._do_handle(args, io)
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clikit/api/command/command.py", line 171, in _do_handle
    return getattr(handler, handler_method)(args, io, self)
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cleo/commands/command.py", line 92, in wrap_handle
    return self.handle()
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/console/commands/build.py", line 30, in handle
    builder.build(fmt)
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/masonry/builder.py", line 19, in build
    builder = self._FORMATS[fmt](self._poetry, self._env, self._io)
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 44, in __init__
    super(WheelBuilder, self).__init__(poetry, env, io)
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/masonry/builders/builder.py", line 68, in __init__
    includes=self._package.include,
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/masonry/utils/module.py", line 72, in __init__
    source=package.get('from'),
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/masonry/utils/package_include.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.check_elements()
  File "/Users/duncan/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/masonry/utils/package_include.py", line 61, in check_elements
    raise ValueError('{} is not a package.'.format(root.name))
```

Am I missing something to tell poetry that this package has no contents?

Addendum: I'm jusy using poetry as a means to creating a `.dist-info` directory populated with metadata, so that `pip` sees the installed metapackae, if there's a better tool for that, I'm happy to switch.

Comment: do you have an __init__.py file in the directory? This is what python requires for it to be considered a package.

Comment: @Jonhasacat, no, this package has exactly zero files.

Comment: I believe this is feasible with _setuptools_ (maybe others as well), in case you are not tied to _poetry_.

Comment: @sinoroc, I am not tied to `poetry`, are you able to post a solution as a separate answer?

Comment: @Duncan I believe it's just a matter of leaving `packages` and `py_modules` out. Are you already familiar with _setuptools_ or not at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With *setuptools* it could look like the following:

`pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools"]
```

`setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
name = metapackage
version = 1.0.0
description = My empty metapackage
authors = Me
license = MIT

[options]
install_requires =
    numpy
```

Note how the [options `packages`, `py_modules`, `scripts`, and `ext_modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.setup) are not populated.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute minimal requirement for a package that you build with poetry is that it contains an importable python module or package.

So you need at least one file that will allow the statement `import metapackage`, which just a folder without any files is not enough to do:

**option 1, with a module**

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
└── metapackage.py  # can be empty
```

**option 2, with a package**

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
└── metapackage
    └── __init__.py  # can be empty
```

Comment: I believe this could be true with _poetry_, but not with _setuptools_ for example.

Comment: @sinoroc I added that information to my post, thanks for pointing it out. I was not aware other build tools can skip over that step.